# How can I implement (I think via inheritance) a new class, with a parameter of the parent class, and a paremeter which comes from another module?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, initialization

My task is:

> 1. Write the code for a class called RandomWalker. This class has only one parameter (an instance variable) called position which is initialized at the creation of a new instance of the class.
> 2. Write a class called Simulation with, at least, the following instance variables: an instance of RandomWalker called random walker, a networkx graph G, a rate parameter lambda_, and an ending time t_end. All those parameters should be assigned during the initialization (using the _*init*_ method).

What I did so far:

```
class RandomWalker:
    def __init__(self, position=0):
        self.position = position
```

saved in my computer as RandomWalker.py. Then:

```
import networkx as nx

class Simulation(RandomWalker):
    def __init__(self, random_walker, G, lambda_, t):
        *self.random_walker = RandomWalker.__init__(self, position)
        *self.nx.Graph() = G
        self.lambda_ = lambda_
        self.t = t
```

The lines starting with "*" are the ones that I think (pretty sure) are wrong, but with the documentation I have and I found browsing, I don't get the right information useful to accomplish this task (which apparently should be easy). It's the first time I work with classes in python. I hope you get the idea of what I was trying to do, any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

No, you don't need to use inheritance in your case - Position is not RandomWalker, but it contains a Random Walker. This is a use case for *composition*, in Python most easily achieved by assigning an object attribute, just like RandomWalker gets `position` attribute.

```
class Simulation:
    def __init__(self, random_walker, G, lambda_, t):
        self.random_walker = random_walker
        self.G = G
        self.lambda_ = lambda_
        self.t = t
```

When creating your `Simulation` object, you need to already have RandomWalker and graph objects created:

```
G = nx.Graph()
random_walker = RandomWalker(position)
simulation = Simulation(random_walker, G, lambda_, t)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! So should I write my code like this:
```
class Simulation:
    def __init__(self, random_walker, G, lambda_, t_end):
        self.random_walker = random_walker
        self.G = G
        self.lambda_ = lambda_
        self.t_end = t_end
        
    G = nx.Graph()
    random_walker = RandomWalker(position)
    simulation = Simulation(random_walker, G, lambda_, t_end)
```
or the definitions of $G$ and random_walker go before definining the class simulation?