# Writing classes that simulate random walks

Tags: python, class, initialization

Regarding a question that I made yesterday: [How can I implement (I think via inheritance) a new class, with a parameter of the parent class, and a paremeter which comes from another module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74462492/how-can-i-implement-i-think-via-inheritance-a-new-class-with-a-parameter-of-t)

Now my task continues this way:

> Create a method of Simulation called get next event that chooses a neighboring node of the current walker’s position uniformly at random and draws a waiting time from an exponential distribution with parameter lambda_. The method should then return the time of the next move and the next position of the walker.

My code now looks like this:

```
import networkx as nx
import random

class RandomWalker:
    def __init__(self, position=0):
        self.position = position
        
class Simulation:
    def __init__(self, random_walker, G, lambda_, t_end):
        self.random_walker = random_walker
        self.G = G
        self.lambda_ = lambda_
        self.t_end = t_end
        
    G = nx.Graph()
    random_walker = RandomWalker(position)
    simulation = Simulation(random_walker, G, lambda_, t_end)
    
    def get_next_event(self, G, lambda_):
        neighbors = list(G.neighbors(random_walker))
        next_event = random.choice(neighbors)
        position = next_event
        waiting_time = np.random.exponential(lambda_)
        return 'Waiting time: '+waiting_time+ '. New position: '+position
```

Since I'm new to the "classes creation method", I still have  in my code (I have python 3.8.1 on Spyder) errors about, for example, *undefined name position* at line 20, and others similar afterwards, although I have them in the classes initialization.

Now, I didn't understand if, when calling variables that were defined in the class initialization, e.g. that one in line 20, i have to write `RandomWalker.position`maybe?
Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Don't invent method names with two leading and trailing underscores. Those are (kind of) reserved for Python itself. And you use `G = nx.Graph()` and the following code lines in the declaration of the class. That doesn't make any sense. You create instances of a class outside of the class after it is defined.

Comment: @Matthias should I write G = nx.Graph()
    random_walker = RandomWalker(position)
    just before defining the class Simulation?